# Slam toolbox and Rviz2 slowing down my computer

Tags: ros, ros2, performance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To describe my problem more accurately, my pc become near unusable when I run slam toolbox and rviz2, with at least 10 seconds between a click and its response (it's really painful)

The robot that I use is a real one, I connect through wifi to it and ssh to launch the node on it but slam and rviz2 run on my computer.

With a simple node to control the robot, they are the only node running and there are no other program that could have a significant impact on the performance

I am running ROS2 foxy on a virtual machine with Kubuntu 20.04

Spec of my PC :

```
System : Windows 10
Processor           12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1250P   1.70 GHz
Installed RAM   16,0 GB (15,2 GB usable)
System type      64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
```

Spec of the virtual machine :

```
12/24 proc core (100 % of the core allocated each)
9110 MB of RAM
128 Mo of video memory
```

Is it a problem with my computer ? or is the virtual machine reducing too much my performance ?

I can of course do any other manipulation you want, just tell me and I will do it as soon as possible

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416772/slam-toolbox-and-rviz2-slowing-down-my-computer/) by [Timothée](https://answers.ros.org/users/148408/timoth%C3%A9e/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2023-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I resolved most of my performance problems so I will post here how I managed to gain performance :

---

Virtual Machine specific :

Reducing the number of core, video memory and RAM **really** improved my performance and I think a good rule of thumb is to not give more than a quarter of your available ressources to the VM. I am currently using 6 cores, 32 Mo and 6 GB of RAM and it work a lot better than before. Check also for any power restriction made by the host on either global performance or your WiFi adapter.

---

System wide changes :

I discovered online that wifi power saver can be **very** detrimental to ROS2 performance over WIFI, and I recommend strongly to deactivate it on both end of the ROS2 communication. To do so :

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Then if you see `wifi.powersave = 3`, change the 3 to a 2 (it disable powersave), save the file, close gedit and restart your machine.

Check also for any power restriction on either global performance or your WiFi adapter.

---

ROS2 specfic :

Switching to CycloneDDS *seems* to work better over WiFi, you can find it [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/DDS-Implementations/Working-with-Eclipse-CycloneDDS.html).
Limiting the info that was transiting through Wifi can help too, but it can't be done in every scenario.

Now I run all the algorithms on the bot, and only use my pc as a visualization / command sender and I can affirm it work really better.

Hope this will help others who struggle with performances !

---

Originally posted by [Timothée](https://answers.ros.org/users/148408/timoth%C3%A9e/) with karma: 23 on 2023-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2023-07-27**:
+1 for circling back and answering